# How do we wait for an async/await function run completely and then run the following line of code in Swift?

Tags: swift, async-await, swift5

How do we wait for an async/await function and then run the following line of code in Swift?

```swift
await res.checkExistingUser(email: loginForm.email)
print("after that") // it doesn't wait for the above function to run completely
```

in the res.checkExistingUser() is used for calling API and mapping the model.

```swift
@MainActor
final class LoginViewModelImpl: LoginViewModel {
    @Published var hasError = false
    @Published private(set) var errorMesg = ""
    @Published private(set) var isFetching = false
    @Published private(set) var isLoggedIn = false
    
    @Published private(set) var isVerify = false
    
    func checkExistingUser(email: String) async {
        self.isFetching = true
        let res = UserServiceImpl()
        
// Call API
        res.checkExistingUser(email: email).responseDecodable(of: BasedResponse<UserExistModel>.self) { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let apiListingResponse):
                print(apiListingResponse)

                if !apiListingResponse.success {
                    self.hasError = true
                    self.errorMesg = String(localized: String.LocalizationValue((apiListingResponse.error?.message)!) )
                    self.isFetching = false
                    break
                }
                
                if (apiListingResponse.payload?.message) != nil {
                    self.isVerify = false
                    self.hasError = true
                    self.errorMesg = String(localized: String.LocalizationValue("verify_email"))
                    self.isFetching = false
                    return
                }
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the function look like?  Why do you think it doesn’t finish running?

Comment: Your question should be, how do I convert an old completion hander to something that is Concurrent?. Watch Meet async await, you need a `CheckedContinutation`. When dealing with true `async await` methods and not just methods that have the `async` keyword the following line after a call is only called after the function has been continued.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show us the method signature for  `responseDecodable`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that `res.checkExistingUser` is not itself a true `async` function.

For `await` to work properly, the method you call must be

(1) Marked `async`.

(2) Actually *be* `async`. This means that all its work must be done either directly or by calling only `async` methods with `await`.

In other words, `async/await` is not magic; it cannot turn what is not `async` into something that *is* `async`. The real work is still up to you.

For example, here's what *not* to do:

```
func func1() async {
    print("start 1")
    await func2()
    print("end 1")
}

func func2() async {
    print("start 2")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        sleep(1)
        print("finished inner 2")
    }
    print("end 2")
}
```

That yields this result:

```
start 1
start 2
end 2
end 1
finished inner 2 (much later)
```

As you can see, `func1` didn't "wait" for everything in `func2` to happen. But that's because `func2` is not truly `async`. *You cannot combine `async/await` with other asynchronous approaches*, such as DispatchQueue!

Here's a corrected version:

```
func func1() async {
    print("start 1")
    await func2()
    print("end 1")
}

func func2() async {
    print("start 2")
    do {
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
        print("finished inner 2")
    }
    print("end 2")
}
```

That does everything in order, and `func1` waits "correctly":

```
start 1
start 2
finished inner 2
end 2
end 1
```

So for your code to work, `checkExistingUser` would need to be itself converted to true `async` and everything it calls would need to be true `async`.

---

Now that you have shown your code, my guess is shown to be correct. `checkExistingUser` is calling a method `res.checkExistingUser` that is asynchronous but is *not* `async`; on the contrary, it takes a *completion handler*. You can't do that. Completion handlers and `async/await` are *opposites*. That is the whole point of `async/await`!

So, that method would either need to be *converted* to true `async` (i.e. be rewriting it), or it would need to be wrapped in a conversion to true `async` (which you can do using `withCheckedThrowingContinuation`, as I explain in [this article](https://www.biteinteractive.com/swift-5-5-asynchronous-looping-with-async-await/).

Comment: It's a pity that the compiler doesn't help you in this kind of situation by pointing out that what you're doing is illegal, but the analysis would doubtless be too time-consuming to be worth the effort. Basically you just have to use your brain!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest watching WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/) which is a nice, practical demonstration of refactoring old completion-handler-based code to `async`-`await`.

For example, as discussed in that video, you can have the compiler create an `async` “wrapper” implementation of `responseDecodable`. E.g., <kbd>control</kbd>-click (or right-click) on the `responseDecodable` implementation and choose “Refactor” » “Add Async Wrapper”, and it will produce an `async` rendition that calls your completion handler rendition.

[image]

Now, you didn't share the function signature of `responseDecodable`, but for illustrative purposes, let us assume it was the following:

```swift
func responseDecodable<T: Decodable>(of dataType: T.Type = T.self, completion: @escaping (BasedResponse<T>) -> Void) {
    …
}
```

Then you can add a wrapper implementation:

```swift
func responseDecodable<T: Decodable>(of dataType: T.Type = T.self) async -> BasedResponse<T> {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        responseDecodable(of: dataType) { result in
            continuation.resume(returning: result)
        }
    }
}
```

Clearly, if your `responseDecodable` was different, just modify that wrapper implementation accordingly. (Or let “Refactor” » “Add Async Wrapper” feature do this for you.) And if `responseDecodable` is from some library you cannot edit, do not worry: Just put your `async` rendition in an `extension` of its original type in your own codebase.

Anyway, you can now replace the incorrect `checkExistingUser`:

```swift
func checkExistingUser(email: String) async {
    self.isFetching = true
    let res = UserServiceImpl()
    
    res.checkExistingUser(email: email).responseDecodable(of: BasedResponse<UserExistModel>.self) { response in
        switch response.result { … }
    }
}
```

With a rendition that will `await` your new `async` implementation of `responseDecodable`:

```swift
func checkExistingUser(email: String) async {
    self.isFetching = true
    let res = UserServiceImpl()
    
    let response = await res.checkExistingUser(email: email).responseDecodable(of: BasedResponse<UserExistModel>.self)

    switch response.result { … }
}
```

You now have an implementation of `checkExistingUser` which will properly `await` the result.

---

Frankly, this process of wrapping a completion handler rendition with an `async` rendition is merely an interim solution. You really want to eventually retire all of your completion handler implementations, altogether. Personally, as advised in that [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/), the pattern I've used in my projects is as follows:

- add an `async` wrapper rendition;
- add a deprecation warning to the completion handler rendition;
- fix all the calling points that are using the completion handler rendition to follow `async`-`await` patterns; and, when all done with that
- go back and

  - refactor the completion handler rendition to follow `async`-`await`, itself
  - retire the wrapper rendition I wrote earlier

---

Note, I did not have a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue, so I made some assumptions in the above. So, do not get bogged down in the details. The idea is to wrap/refactor your completion handler method with an `async` one that uses `withCheckedContinuation` (or `withThrowingCheckedContinuation`), and now you can `await` a function that formerly had a completion handler.

Comment: As an aside, as you transition to `async`-`await`, you not only want to refactor your completion handler methods to `async`, but you also probably want to eliminate all of these `Result` types, too. But you appear to have baked `Result` types into other types, which might make this more complicated than usual. If, after making a good faith effort yourself, you still need help with that, you might want to post a complete example to https://codereview.stackexchange.com and some of us might possibly be able to help further. I sense an opportunity to dramatically simplify your object model.